# Access rails server running on Vagrant box from Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, vagrant

I'm on a Windows machine, and have a Vagrant box running `ubuntu/xenial64`, with Rails installed on it. When I ssh into the box and create a rails app, `cd` into the folder and run `rails server`, it tells me

> Rails 5.1.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>
> Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000

I now want to visit `localhost:3000` on my Windows machine but it says not found. How do I make the rails server available to Windows?

Comment: You need to access using IP address

Comment: Also you need to start server using `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: I have tried starting with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` and also tried accessing with `127.0.0.1:3000`, still "not found".

Comment: No, check what is the IP address from the terminal in vagrant box

Comment: run this on terminal `ifconfig`

Comment: Ok - I do that and get for `enp0s3`:  `inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`. But visiting those gets a "connection timed out" response.

Comment: Check @shubham-wadzirkar's answer that might help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure you have forwarded port 3000 from your VM to your host machine, add this line in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

This way you'll be able to access the rails app from `localhost:3000` on the Windows machine

As other said, its best to start the rails server using `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` so its bound to all the network interfaces

Answer (score 3):

I am using VirtualBox(running Ubuntu 14) for my rails app.I have done the following changes to access localhost on my Windows machine

**Step 1**

- Go to *Settings -> Network* and change **NAT Adapter** to **Bridged Adapter**. Also in *Network -> Advance* check **Allow All** for Promiscuous Mode.
- Restart your VM/box

**Step 2**

- Now follow your process until you run the `rails server` command. Just modify the command to this `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` and wait for the server to start.
- Get the IP address of your box(run ifconfig) and now in your Windows open up any browser and give the URL as ip_address_of_your_box:3000

  eg : http://10.0.0.191:3000